# Show data of 2 users on one page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, userid

I have created an app where a user can create 2 profiles under one account. Users can create one profile for an artist and another for a venue.

On the 'my listings' page, users can view cards with minor details of their profiles. When a card is pressed the user is then brought to the full profile page where they can view all info of the profile.

The problem is when I click on a venue it tries to show me an artist page (photos below)

[display of both profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcjLj.png)

[loading screen when click on venue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOjUg.png)

[artist profile display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNJFV.png)

does anyone know why this might be happening?
Or know of a way of fixing it?

tab4.page.ts:

```
releventVenue: Venue[];
  relevantArtist: Artist[];
  isLoading = false;
  private artistSub: Subscription;
  private venueSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private artistService: ArtistService,
    private venueService: VenueService,
    private authService: AuthService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.artistSub = this.artistService.artist.subscribe(artist => {
      this.relevantArtist = artist;
      this.authService.userId.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(userId => {
        this.relevantArtist = this.relevantArtist.filter(
          artist => artist.userId === userId
        );
      });
    });
    this.venueSub = this.venueService.venue.subscribe(venue => {
      this.releventVenue = venue;
      this.authService.userId.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(userId => {
        this.releventVenue = this.releventVenue.filter(
          venue => venue.userId === userId
        );
      });
    });
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.artistService.fetchArtist().subscribe(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
    this.venueService.fetchVenue().subscribe(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.artistSub) {
      this.artistSub.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.venueSub) {
      this.venueSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

tab4.page.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2">
        <ion-card
          *ngFor="let artist of relevantArtist"
          fill="clear"
          [routerLink]="['/','tabs','tab4','tab4',artist.id]"
        >
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{ artist.name }}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle
              >{{ artist.cost | currency: "€" }} / Night</ion-card-subtitle
            >
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-img [src]="artist.imageUrl"></ion-img>
          <ion-card-content>
            <p>Genre: {{ artist.genre }}</p>
            <p>Equipment: {{ artist.equipment }}</p>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>


    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2">
        <ion-card
          *ngFor="let venue of releventVenue"
          fill="clear"
          [routerLink]="['/','tabs','tab4','tab4',venue.id]"
        >
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{ venue.name }}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle
              >{{ venue.cost | currency: "€" }} / Night</ion-card-subtitle
            >
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-img [src]="venue.imageUrl"></ion-img>
          <ion-card-content>
            <p>Genre: {{ venue.genre }}</p>
            <p>Equipment: {{ venue.equipment }}</p>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

tabs-routing.module.ts:

```
path: 'tab4',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => import('../tab4/tab4.module').then(m => m.Tab4PageModule)
          },
          {
            path: 'tab4/:artistId',
            loadChildren: () => import('../tab4/my-artist/my-artist.module').then(m => m.MyArtistPageModule)
          },
          {
            path: 'tab4/:venueId',
            loadChildren: () => import('../tab4/my-venue/my-venue.module').then(m => m.MyVenuePageModule)
          },
```

Comment: You have conflicting routes, I would suggest you change them to reflect each type. `artist/:aristId` /  `venue/:venueId` you already have `tab4` as parent don't need to repeat that.

Comment: It's always the simplest of things that mess me up. That worked! thanks.